# How to get radar chart coordinates using getValueForDistanceFromCenter with Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, radar-chart

I am experimenting with [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/radar.html) to build [radar charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart). I mastered the basics (see basic chart below), but I would like to use the **x y coordinates** of the graph to place texts directly on the canvas.

After some digging, I found out that it is not possible to use `getValueForPixel` or `getPixelForTick` in a radar chart. See this [github issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5931). In the connecting thread, a new method `getValueForDistanceFromCenter` is introduced.

As I understand it, it would be possible to calculate the distance from the `center` with this method, and use it to get coordinates. I searched the Chart.js documentation and other sites, but cannot find any code examples or information on how to implement this.

Can somebody point me in the right direction how to implement the method in the code?

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["Ball Skills", "Shooting", "Physical"],
  datasets: [{
    label: [`ikke`, `jij`],
    backgroundColor: "rgba(38,120,255,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(38,120,255, 1)",
    data: [90, 90, 90]
  }]
};

var options = {
  responsive: true,
  tooltips: false,
  title: {
    text: 'Basic example',
    display: true,
    position: `bottom`,
  },
  scale: {
    angleLines: {
      display: true
    },
    ticks: {
      suggestedMin: 0,
      suggestedMax: 100,
      stepSize: 25,
      maxTicksLimit: 11,
      display: false,
    }
  },
  legend: {
    labels: {
      padding: 10,
      fontSize: 14,
      lineHeight: 30,
    },
  },
};

var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: 'radar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

Comment: I cannot find a code snippet on the site Chart.js. The method getDistanceFromCenterForValue is described in the interface section on the website of Chart.js. --> https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/api/interfaces/RadialLinearScale.html and near the middle. Further more i can find the method in the basecode of Chart.js --> https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/7b621d7/types/index.esm.d.ts#L3389I. More searching on Codepen/stackoverflow and google gave me no hits.

Answer (score 0):

The `radialLinear` scale (in version 2.9.4 that I have seen your are using version 2) there is the method `getValueForDistanceFromCenter(value)` to get the distance from center but there is another method `getPointPositionForValue(index, value)` which can provide you the point at a specif index of your data.

To use them and to draw what you want on chart using those points, you need to implement a plugin.
In the below snippet, I'm drawing a rect between the points at a specific value.

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
const data = {
  labels: ["Ball Skills", "Shooting", "Physical"],
  datasets: [{
    label: [`ikke`, `jij`],
    backgroundColor: "rgba(38,120,255,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(38,120,255, 1)",
    data: [50, 50, 50]
  }]
};

const options = {
  responsive: true,
  tooltips: false,
  title: {
    text: 'Basic example',
    display: true,
    position: `bottom`,
  },
  scale: {
    angleLines: {
      display: true
    },
    ticks: {
      suggestedMin: 0,
      suggestedMax: 100,
      stepSize: 25, 
      maxTicksLimit: 11,
      display: false, 
    }
  },
  legend: {
    labels: {
      padding: 10,
      fontSize: 14,
      lineHeight: 30,
    },
  },
};

const plugin = {
  id: 'getDistance',
  afterDraw(chart) {
    const c = chart.ctx;
    const rScale = chart.scale;
    c.save();
    chart.data.datasets[0].data.forEach(function(item, index) {
      const point = rScale.getPointPositionForValue(0.5 + index, 50);
      c.beginPath();
      c.fillStyle = 'red';
      c.fillRect(point.x - 5, point.y - 5, 10, 10);
      c.fill();
    });
    c.restore();
  }
};

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'radar',
  plugins: [plugin],
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```